# Which attribute in XSD will annotate a field with @XmlElement(required = false) in JAXB generated classes

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, jaxb2, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I want to annotate a field in my jaxb generated class with this annotation - @XmlElement(required = false). Which attribute in the XSD would generate my field with this annotation?. 
I can't hand type this as the JAXB classes are auto generated using Maven every time a build is run.

My jaxb version is xjc 2.2.4-2

Thanks

Comment: My requirement is to make the field optional. I understand that if I declare the field to be `micOccurs=0` in the XSD it would do the job. But when I did so, xjc is not adding the `@XmlElement(required = false)` annotation by default to the field in the jaxb class.

Comment: Another interesting observation is that when I hand type the annotation to the field in the jaxb class and use JDK's `schemagen` to tool to generate the schema from jaxb classes, I see that the field is added with `minOccurs=0` attribute in the generated schema

Answer (score 1):

When an element has `minOccurs="0"` the corresponding `@XmlElement` has `required=false`.  Note that `false` is the default value of the `required` attribute so it may not actually appear in the generated annotation.

---

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment:

> Let me explain my actual problem. I'm using Jackson to generate the
>   JSON from the JAXB classes. Issue is when the element  is not
>   present in the xml, I see the json output with the field name as 'pip'
>   and value as null. I am actually expecting the field 'pip' to be
>   absent from my json output as I declared it to be minOccurs=0 in the
>   XSD. Can't figure out if it's an issue with JAXB or Jackson.
>   Interestingly when I annotate the field explicitly with required=false
>   in the jaxb class, I see my expected output with the field being
>   absent

This is an issue with Jackson not handling the default value of the `required` property on the `@XmlElement` annotation correctly.

Comment: Thanks Blaise. Exactly that's what I was hoping but that's the case here. Following are the code snippets.  XSD  `<xs:element name="pip" type="pipType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>`  JAXB  `protected List<PipType> pip;`

Comment: @GangaAloori - I have update my answer with some info that should help.

Comment: Thanks again. Helpful. Let me explain my actual problem. I'm using Jackson to generate the JSON from the JAXB classes. Issue is when the element <pip> is not present in the xml, I see the json output with the field name as 'pip' and value as null. I am actually expecting the field 'pip' to be absent from my json output as I declared it to be `minOccurs=0` in the XSD. Can't figure out if it's an issue with JAXB or Jackson.  Interestingly when I annotate the field explicitly with `required=false` in the jaxb class, I see my expected output with the field being absent

Comment: @GangaAloori - I have updated my answer.  This is an issue with Jackson not handling the default value of the `required` attribute on the `@XmlElement` annotation correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the update. JAXB doesn't generate `@XmlElement` annotation at all for that field. I've posted the element declaration in XSD and the generated field in JAXB class in my previous comment above.